# Limiting height multiple background images CSS

Tags: css, background-image

Please bear with me as I'm gonna try to explain this as best that I can. I'm trying to create a changeable 3D-cube and I have so far done this using background images on classes .back and .front. Now, the problem is that my background called "right-side-fill.jpg" (.front) fills all the way down past the bottom edge.

[image]

The image "bottomfront-side-fill.jpg" is a blue pixel with white fill at the bottom to cover up the 45° line. I've tried `background-clip` and `background-origin`, but can't seem to get it right.

Demo: http://rollodesigns.com/fishyfish/kalkylatorn.php

```
.back{
  background: url('../img/top-left-corner.jpg'),
            url('../img/top-right-corner.jpg'),
            url('../img/bottom-left-corner.jpg'),
            url('../img/top-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/bottom-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/left-side-fill.jpg');
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, top, bottom, left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y;

  padding-right: 103px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.front{
  background: url('../img/right-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/top-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/bottomfront-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/left-side-fill.jpg'),
            white;
  background-position: right, top, bottom, left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y;

  padding-right: 172px;
  padding-bottom: 133px;
}


<div class="aquarium-wrapper">
<div class="back" style="position: relative; width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
<div class="front" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the correct idea in mind. Setting `background-clip` as `content-box` is the correct option to stop the background from going below the element but the problem was with `background-position`. Since you had set `background-position` as `right` (which means box's right edge), it would never get shown as the `padding-right` is 172px which is equal to the width of the image.

Instead of that, set the `background-position` as `298px` or as `calc(100% - 2px)`. When any one of these choices are used the left-most 2px of the image will fall within the content area of the box and thus would be visible.

```
.front{
  background: url('../img/right-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/top-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/bottomfront-side-fill.jpg'),
            url('../img/left-side-fill.jpg'),
            white;
  background-position: calc(100% - 2px), top, bottom, left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y;
  background-clip: content-box, content-box, content-box, content-box, border-box;
  padding-right: 172px;
  padding-bottom: 133px;
}
```

**Note:** The image alignment is not proper and you'd need to adjust the width/height of the elements but I think you would be able to figure that out.

Comment: You are absolutely right! That did it. Very informative answer as well. Thank you!